# Show confirmation modal on selectize remove_button plugin

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I am using selectize.js library with the remove_button plugin.

When the user clicks on the x to remove a certain label, I want a confirmation modal to show up and ask "are you sure you want to delete  as a label?". After clicking yes, the entry in selectize would then be deleted. If the user does not click yes the entry should just remain.

I read the [plugin documentation](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/plugins.md) on selectize and especially the "Dom Events" part.

It shows this code:

```
Selectize.define('remove_button', function(options) {
        var self = this;

        // override the setup method to add an extra `click`  handler
        this.setup = (function() {
            var original = self.setup;
            return function() {
                original.apply(this, arguments);
                this.$control.on('click', 'div', function(e) {
                    console.log("clicked");
                });
            };
        })();

    });
```

However, when I type in values in my selectize, the layout of the "x" button dissapears (however it is still there and clickable, but it just hides). While clicking the button shows my console.log output, but does not remove the value at all. I was expecting original.apply(this, arguments); to make sure that it is still being deleted, but it does not work?